# Tools to manage a portable workstation configuration

Tags: dotfiles

I have 3 computers I work on regularly - a work laptop, personal laptop and home PC. I also have .rc files for vim, bash, zsh, git, hg etc that I need to maintain across the 3 physical computers. Currently I am using a publicly hosted hg repository to keep the rc files synchronized between the 3 computers, but it still feels like a very manual process.

Is there an open source tool that makes it easier to synchronize rc files across multiple computers?

Comment: Also asked in superuser.com: http://superuser.com/questions/1052173/tools-to-manage-a-portable-workstation-configuration

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Comment: With 38k+ rep I would expect you to know basic things like not crossposting :/

Comment: And you should also know that asking for software rec (tools) is off-topic.

Comment: @DavidPostill you'd also think they'd know not to post a garbage answer 8 months later. I suspect a hijacked account, after many years of inactivity.

Comment: @miken32 Or he is hat hunting :)

Comment: @DavidPostill: Or he's suffering from brain damage from Too Much PHP. :P

Comment: @DavidPostill: *sigh*. I posted that answer in the hope that it would help other people discover https://dotfiles.github.io/ which is a fantastic resource for programmers, but hard to find if you don't know to google the word "dotfiles". I earned most of my rep many years ago by answering questions and helping people regardless of whether or not the questions fit the guidelines, and I'm saddened to see that the next generation of stackoverflowers are more interested in finding excuses to downvote and delete content than they are in helping other people.

Answer (score -1):

You can have your shell update your local repo on login, then `source` your files.

All this should come with a check if your local repo is head.

Pseudo code time as I'm at work and dont have `hg` installed

```
if [[ test if sync needed ]]; then do;
    hg update repo
    source dotfiles.sh
done;
```